# Java Program not taking the Piped input

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I have to work with a Java program which takes 2 user inputs like this:

```
Enter username:
Enter password:
```

So I thought of sending it like

```
echo -e "myusername\npassword" | java javaprogram
```

and

```
java javaprogram < input.txt
```

Both didn't work.

When I execute this command it's showing the error like this:

```
Enter userID: Enter password: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to mask input in console. at..
```

I don't know the source code of this jar file.

What can be the reason for this ?

Comment: Did you try below? java javaprogram username password

Comment: @Srivignesh It's prompting for user input and not taking the command line arguments

Comment: jd-gui tool is a lightweight decompiler which will help in viewing the source code

Comment: `"myusername\npassword\n"` a newline on last line? Though that error is something else...

Comment: @JoopEggen `echo` appends a newline to its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible that the program isn't reading the password from standard input, but from the terminal.  There is a program called `expect`, which is basically a language for scripting interactions with terminal programs.

Take a look at http://expect.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) which helps with programmed dialogue with interactive programs. Additionally, in case you want to know more about the source of the *.jar file you are using, you can decompile it.